# Assign struct pointer to interface pointer

Tags: go, pointers, interface

I'm trying to refactor some golang source code, and I would like to use interfaces but I find huge difficulties (bear with me, I'm a hard-core C/C++ orphan)

I extracted a small sample exhibiting the error I get

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type LogProcessor interface {
    Init() int
}

type MyProcessor struct {
    a int
}

func (m MyProcessor) Init() int {
    return m.a
}

func main() {
    t := &(MyProcessor{2})
    var p *LogProcessor = &(MyProcessor{4}) //!!!fails!!!
    fmt.Println((*t).Init(), (*p).Init())
}
```

Why is the second assignment failing?

---

Adding the code modified to demonstrate what I was trying to do. I thought interfaces where more similar to C++ classes. My fault. Still learning

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type LogProcessor interface {
    Init() int
}

type MyProcessor struct {
    a int
}

func (m *MyProcessor) Init() int {
    m.a++
    return m.a
}

func main() {
    t := &(MyProcessor{2})
    m := MyProcessor{4}
    var p LogProcessor = &m
    fmt.Println(t.Init(), p.Init())
    fmt.Println(t.a, m.a)
}
```

Comment: Pointers to interfaces are almost never used in Go, so `p` should be just `LogProcessor`. You also don't need to do `(*t).Init()`, it's enough to do `t.Init()` and let the compiler to convert it automatically to `(*t).Init()`.

Comment: someone more experienced in those two languages will hopefully answer you. But you have those resources to help you transition https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoForCPPProgrammers and https://talks.golang.org/2012/goforc.slide#1 (your manner to write Go code is hardcore ; )

Comment: @mkopriva but doesn't this become passed by value then?

Comment: @aturetta yes, but that's ok, almost always. The only time a pointer-to-interface makes sense is if you are using indirection to assign an interface variable. Other than that it is of no importance that the interface is passed around by value. What specific concerns do you have regarding pass-by-value?

Comment: @mkopriva what if my struct implementing the interface had a huge array of bytes...

Comment: @aturetta you'd pass a pointer to the struct and make sure that it implements the interface using a pointer receiver instead of a value receiver.

Comment: So, thanks @mkopriva for giving me nightmares :-)

Now I understand the go syntax is stranger than I already knew

I editet the code to reflect what I intended to demonstrate, but that I be damned if I understand why it works

Comment: @aturetta btw in cases where you have to use a pointer to an interface you'll need to do the initialization in two steps https://play.golang.org/p/MAg0N3xD-6F

Comment: Thinking in C++ while trying to write Go code (or vice versa!) is a recipe for disaster.  (I've done both)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `MyProcessor{2}` is a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). It is valid to take the address of a composite literal, and it will be of type `*MyProcessor`.

So here:

```
t := &(MyProcessor{2})
```

Type of `t` will be `*MyProcessor`.

Your failing line:

```
var p *LogProcessor = &(MyProcessor{4}) //!!!fails!!!
```

The type of the expression on the right hand side is again `*MyProcessor`. It's a pointer to a concrete type. The type of `p` is `*LogProcessor`, it's a pointer to another type. [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules don't apply here, so the value is simply not assignable to the variable `p`.

Note that there is an assignability rule:

> A value `x` is assignable to a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - ...
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `T`.

In your example `p`'s type is not an interface type, but a pointer to interface. You rarely (if ever) need this in go.

Instead if you use "just" the interface type:

```
var p LogProcessor = &(MyProcessor{4}) // This works!
```

This works because the concrete type `*MyProcessor` implements the interface type `LogProcessor`. You also don't need the parenthesis, you may simply use `&MyProcessor{4}`.

Then of course you can't dereference `p` (as it's not a pointer), so you have to use `p.Init()`.

Answer (score 1):

it is failing because you are using a pointer to an interface, if you remove the pointer to LogProcessor for var p it works

```
package main

import "fmt"

type LogProcessor interface {
    Init() int
}

type MyProcessor struct {
    a int
}

func (m MyProcessor) Init() int {
    return 2
}

func main() {
    t := &(MyProcessor{2})
    var p LogProcessor = MyProcessor{4} // works without a pointer to  the interface type
    fmt.Println((*t).Init(), (p).Init())
}
```