# Instantiate generic interface with any, struct doesn't implement it

Tags: go, generics, interface

Can someone explain, why `*DataTo` does not satisfy `ToType[any]`?

Trying to build a `DTOer`, that copies all values of one struct to another and also sets some explicit values (`V` in this case)

https://go.dev/play/p/-oobZrw5Ewe

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

type DataFrom struct {
    V1 int
}

type DataTo struct {
    V int
}

func (m *DataTo) SetVal() {
    m.V = 1
    return
}

type ToType[T any] interface {
    SetVal()
    *T
}

type DTO[TFrom any, TTo ToType[any]] struct {
    Get func(from TFrom) TTo
}

func main() {
    dto := &DTO[DataFrom, *DataTo]{
        Get: func(from DataFrom) *DataTo {
            return &DataTo{V: from.V1 + 666}
        },
    }

    vFrom := DataFrom{V1: 1}
    vTo := dto.Get(vFrom)

    fmt.Println(vTo.V)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because `any` is a static type.**

If you use it to instantiate a generic type like `ToType`, that generic type will expect exactly `any`.

Now, certain usages of the type parameter might hide this issue, for example:

```
type Foo[T any] struct {
    Value T
}

Foo[any]{Value: 12} // ok
```

Normally you are able to assign whatever type to `any` like the above, because `any` is just an alias of the empty interface `interface{}`, and any type satisfies the empty interface.

When the type parameter is used in composite types such as `*T`, then instantiating with `any` means **exactly `*any`**. Therefore you can imagine `ToType[any]` as the same thing as:

```
type ToTypeAny interface {
    SetVal()
    *any
}
```

And then `*DataTo` is obviously not `*any`. Further details: [Assign struct pointer to interface pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725213/assign-struct-pointer-to-interface-pointer)

If you declare the struct as follows it will compile:

```
type DTO[TFrom any, TTo ToType[DataTo]] struct {
    Get func(from TFrom) TTo
}
```

Or in a more "generic" but also more verbose way:

```
type DTO[TFrom any, T any, TTo ToType[T]] struct {
    Get func(from TFrom) TTo
}

&DTO[DataFrom, DataTo, *DataTo]{ ... }
```